# How to Redirect URL using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect URLs by using the `.htaccess` file:

`index.php?i=Dengue-NS1-ELISA-kit---Antigen&id=682&cat=0`

to

`index.php?i=Dengue-NS1-ELISA-kit---Antigen&id=682&cat=17`

Notice the **17** on the end there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code that you need to put in .htaccess file under DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)(?:^|&)cat=0(&.*|)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ index.php?%1%2&cat=17 [L,NC,R]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here maybe you can use this tool I use it all the time http://www.htaccessredirect.net/

Comment: I would like to redirect a url to a different url, I can not find any option in this http://www.htaccessredirect.net/ to redirect url

Comment: Hmmmm I don't think you can do that with htaccess, but for PHP you can use `<?php echo"<meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com'>"?>`

Comment: There is no specific page/file for that! index.php for both, so I can not use meta tags